# Multiple commands for single button text from the button and also run a function tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I have list of buttons and I need to know how i can get the text of the button on which the user clicks and also run a command function for the same.

the code mentioned at the end helps me print the text but i need that value in another variable. How can that be done.

How do i run another function after finding the text.

if i just change the command = check_user in the below mentioned code it runs the function

But i need to run the function as well as get the text of the button

all_accidental_case_except_close is a dataframe - the index values are the text to be printed on the button. The number of buttons will keep on changing based on certain conditions.

code:

```
bt_list = []

for idx, value in enumerate(all_accidental_case_except_close.index):

    b = Button(root, text = value, command = lambda c = idx: print(bt_list[c].cget("text")))
    bt_list.append(b)
    b.grid(row = idx + 2, column = 1)
```

Comment: Why not just simply create another function to call whatever you want and set this function as the command option of the button?

Comment: How do we create a function to find which button is clicked. Then both the function can be added into one function.

Comment: a way around what i did was using the combobox which would help me get what is clicked and also use the funtion

Comment: You can simply create a function, for example `button_clicked(btntext)`, and call it inside the lambda function of the button: `lambda c=idx: button_cllicked(bt_list[c].cget('text'))`.  Then inside the `button_clicked(btntext)` function, you can print the button text and you can do whatever you want as you know which button is clicked based on the button text.

Comment: thanks acw1668 it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by usind `bind_all` function and `event.widget['text']`:

```
from tkinter import *

def do(evt):
    print(evt.widget['text'])

tk = Tk()
b = Button(tk,text='click me!')
b.pack()

b2 = Button(tk,text='click you!')
b2.pack()

b.bind_all('<Button-1>', do)
```

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: you don't need to call `bind_all` more than once.